# Callback for jquery.zrssfeed.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, rss, feed

zrssfeed.min.js to parse my Yahoo Pipes feed.

I need to fetch data from the structure built by the the plugin (i mean Parsing) and then insert the fetched data into other DOM elements.

I need a callback function to the function call to jquery.zrssfeed.min.js so that fetch data from its structure would be at ease.

How do I call the callback function? I mean i want the syntax. Where do I insert the call to the function in here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
    limit: 5
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the [documentation](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/):

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
    limit: 5
   }, 
   function (e) {
        // there you go
   }
  });
});
```

see source of this [example-page](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_ticker.html) for usage