# jquery rss with show more feature

Tags: jquery, rss, show

I was trying to add a show more button or div as in this example here [show more button](http://jsfiddle.net/Ma8AW/) to my jquery rss I made here [Jquery rss feed](http://jsfiddle.net/fxdigi/HLCxV/). The problem is that I tried many times to wrap the rss div with a div wrapper and force it to display few lines only, but it didn't work...

so all I want is to hide all rss feeds except say top 3 only. Then whenever I want to show more of the feed threads, I simply click **Show more** button...

This is the show more button with javascript:

Jquery show button

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    $("ul").append("<li>" + i + "</li>");
}

var $li = $("li"),
    chunk = 5;

console.log(chunk, $li);

$li.slice(chunk).hide();

$("button").click(function() {
    $li.filter(":hidden").slice(0, chunk).show();
});
```

html show button

```
<ul></ul>
<button>Show more</button>
```

jquery rss:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture/', {
    limit:100
  });
});
```

rss html:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

any idea how I have to do in order to show only the first 3 or say 5 feeds and hide the rest. And display each 3 or 5 feed after clicking the **show more button**...??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something called a `callback` option in zRSSfeed.js. This indicates the point when the feed is in your DOM, kinda like a completion state. See [example](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_ticker.html) and a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802845/callback-for-jquery-zrssfeed-min-js) for more info on that. **Note that you must be using [the latest version of zRSSfeed.js (1.2.0)](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/zrssfeed-120.zip) for this to work.**. So, using this callback option, you could control the your feed through JavaScript. So it looks something like this:

```
$('#test').rssfeed(feedURL, options , function (e) {
    var $li = $("#test").find(".rssRow"),
        chunk = 3;

    //hide rows > 3
    $li.slice(chunk).hide()

   //insert button after ul
   $("ul").after("<button>Show more</button>");

   //event handler for button
   $("button").click(function () {
      //get the elements hidden            
      var el = $li.filter(":hidden");
      //to hide show more for last click (there aren't any more elements
      if (el.length <= chunk) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
      //show next 3 rows
      el.slice(0, chunk).show();
  });
```

});

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HLCxV/7/

Comment: That was an amazing answer. Thanks @passionateCoder so much. You are a life saver. Thanks again, mate.

Comment: i edited the answer to make the show more logic match the one in question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing that.